# how to set username and password for Apache localhost. Need to upload files

Tags: html

setting username and password for Apache localhost. I want to be able to upload files using FTP protocal through the localhost, which means the localhost needs a username and password to enter. I am trying to test everything before I subscribe to a web server.

I have Apache 2.4 and PHP 7 installed on my windows 10 computer (no tomcat, no sql server or anything else). Using an html IDE I have written an index.html and other related files (css, php, js) and copied them (using windows) into the C:/Apache24/htdocs folder. I open a browser and type in localhost/index.html and everything is nicely displayed. But I won't be able to copy files to a subscribed server without knowing its username and password and connecting to it first.

I have read at least 50 discussions on Stack Overflow, Code Project and others but none of them address setting username and password without tomcat or sql server or something else.

As an aside, I was successful in password protecting a folder inside of htdocs using .htaccess and .htpasswd. I had trouble initially because I was missing the required Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable(64) file.

Comment: You do know, that Apache is not an FTP but a HTTP server?

Answer (score 1):

Apache is a HTTP server! So you can't access it via FTP. 
If you need to upload files you should create a form and coding server-side script in order to make upload in a subfolder of your apache root.